# How to make OpenAPI codegen understand that it is necessary to decode an XML and not a JSON response into reusable data in PHP during generation?

Tags: php, openapi, openapi-generator

I'm trying to generate my openapi.yaml specification :

```
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: OpenAPI 3.0
  description: |-
    This is a sample Server based on the OpenAPI 3.0 specification.  You can find out more about
    Swagger at [https://swagger.io](https://swagger.io).
  contact:
    email: test@example.net
  version: 1.0.11
externalDocs:
  description: Find out more about OpenAPI Codegen
  url: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator
servers:
  - url: https://server.io/api/v3/
    description: Api Server
tags:
  - name: Test
    description: Tests endpoints
    externalDocs:
      description: Find out more
      url: https://test.com/sales/
paths:
  /stations.html:
    get:
      tags:
        - Test
      summary: Get existing test stations
      description: Get all existing test stations
      operationId: getStations
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: agent
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
            default: "TEST123"
          description: The company’s Unique Code
      responses:
        "200":
          $ref: "#/components/responses/Station"
        "404":
          description: Not found
components:
  responses:
    Station:
      description: Successful response
      content:
        application/xml:
          schema:
            $ref: "#/components/schemas/StationResponse"
  schemas:
    StationResponse:
      description: XML parent root response
      type: object
      xml:
        name: response
        namespace: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
        prefix: xsd
      properties:
        station:
          type: array
          xml:
            name: station
          items:
            $ref: "#/components/schemas/Station"
    Station:
      description: A test available stations.
      type: object
      properties:
        code:
          type: string
          xml:
            attribute: true
        name:
          type: string
          xml:
            attribute: true
        lat:
          type: string
          xml:
            attribute: true
        long:
          type: string
          xml:
            attribute: true
        icon:
          type: string
          xml:
            attribute: true
        StationInformation:
          $ref: "#/components/schemas/StationInformation"
    StationInformation:
      description: The more information station.
      type: object
      properties:
        StationType:
          type: string
          xml:
            attribute: true
        Tax1Percent:
          type: string
          xml:
            attribute: true
        Tax2Percent:
          type: string
          xml:
            attribute: true
        Tax1Name:
          type: string
          xml:
            attribute: true
        Tax2Name:
          type: string
          xml:
            attribute: true
```

When I generate it with the command `openapi-generator-cli generate -i openapi.yaml -g php -o app/Http/OpenApiClients` everything works.

When I try to dump the code and follow its progress I find in way that it transforms the xml response into a string then tries to decode it into json `json_decode`:

```
/**
     * Operation getStationsWithHttpInfo
     *
     * Get existing wheelsys stations
     *
     * @param  string $agent The company’s Unique Code (required)
     * @param  string $contentType The value for the Content-Type header. Check self::contentTypes['getStations'] to see the possible values for this operation
     *
     * @throws \OpenAPI\Client\ApiException on non-2xx response
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
     * @return array of \OpenAPI\Client\Model\StationResponse, HTTP status code, HTTP response headers (array of strings)
     */
    public function getStationsWithHttpInfo($agent, string $contentType = self::contentTypes['getStations'][0])
    {
        $request = $this->getStationsRequest($agent, $contentType);

        try {
            // ...

            switch ($statusCode) {
                case 200:
                    if ('\OpenAPI\Client\Model\StationResponse' === '\SplFileObject') {
                        $content = $response->getBody(); //stream goes to serializer
                    } else {
                        $content = (string) $response->getBody();
                        if ('\OpenAPI\Client\Model\StationResponse' !== 'string') {
                            $content = json_decode($content);
                        }
                    }

                    return [
                        ObjectSerializer::deserialize($content, '\OpenAPI\Client\Model\StationResponse', []),
                        $response->getStatusCode(),
                        $response->getHeaders()
                    ];
            }

            // ...
        } catch (ApiException $e) {
            switch ($e->getCode()) {
                case 200:
                    $data = ObjectSerializer::deserialize(
                        $e->getResponseBody(),
                        '\OpenAPI\Client\Model\StationResponse',
                        $e->getResponseHeaders()
                    );
                    $e->setResponseObject($data);
                    break;
            }
            throw $e;
        }
    }
```

Of course it doesn't work since it's not a valid json. I want to avoid modifying the generated code. what could be the solution to this blockage ?

Comment: It also has an interesting line `if ('\OpenAPI\Client\Model\StationResponse' === '\SplFileObject') {` - a solution is to learn to write it yourself.